# Why fetch throws badrequest in React when calling C# API with formdata?

Tags: c#, reactjs, .net, fetch, 400-bad-request

So to be more specific, I created a C# API. It works nice, I can call requests in any controller fine. But when it comes to sending a POST request to upload two files it says bad request, error 400 and just stops.

Here is the code of the API

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateBook([FromForm]IFormFile cover, [FromForm]IFormFile file, [FromForm]string title, [FromForm]string metaData, [FromForm]string description, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {

            if (cover == null || file == null)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            await using var stream = new MemoryStream();
            await file.CopyToAsync(stream);

            var id = Guid.NewGuid();
            var fileExt = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
            var coverExt = Path.GetExtension(cover.FileName);
            var docName = $"{id}{fileExt}";
            var coverName = $"{id}{coverExt}";

            var bookDoc = new S3Obj()
            {
                BucketName = Constants.bucketName,
                InputStream = stream,
                Name = Constants.bookPath + docName
            };
            var bookCover = new S3Obj()
            {
                BucketName = Constants.bucketName,
                InputStream = stream,
                Name = Constants.bookCoverPath + docName
            };
            var cred = new Credentials()
            {
                AccessKey = Constants.accessKey,
                SecretKey = Constants.secretKey
            };
            var docResponse = await StorageService.Singleton.UploadFileAsync(bookDoc, cred);
            var coverResponse = await StorageService.Singleton.UploadFileAsync(bookCover, cred);
            Console.WriteLine(docResponse.Message);
            Book book = new Book() { Id = id, Title = title, MetaData = metaData, Description = description, Cover = coverName, DocumentPath = docName };
            return Ok(await Mediator.Send(new CreateBook.Command() { Book = book }, cancellationToken));
        }
```

Then this code is called from a React app in fetch, with the following:

```
  const sendRequest = () => {
        var base = process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL;
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append('cover', cover);
        data.append('file', file);
        data.append('title', title);
        data.append('metaData', meta);
        data.append('description', description);

        fetch(base + "/Book",{ method: 'POST', body: data, headers:{'Content-Type':'multi-part/formdata'} }).then(succes => { console.log(succes); console.log(data); window.location.reload() }).catch(e => {console.log(e); console.log(data);});
    }
```

I am stuck with this and I have to finish it fast, but I just can't get it to work, I am not really great at frontend. I also tried passing other parameters in the url, instead of formdata and leaving only the 2 files in formdata, but there was no change.

I am appreciating any help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it work in Postman or other similar tool?

Comment: Are you able to make api request from other client like postman with post and 2 files and is there it's working or not can you check it. And can you give screenshot of network tab with details on what is getting sent from browser.

Comment: @GuruStron everything works fine in swagger

Answer (score 0):

Try passing this in header

```
'content-Type': 'multipart/form-data
```

Comment: If you check the question - it should already be present - `headers:{'Content-Type':'multi-part/formdata'}`

Comment: It is already present